# Encountering type safety warning when using Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have a class that looks like this.

```
class SuperClass<T> {
    public <K extends ClassB> K someMethod(T t) {
        return null;
    }
}

class ClassB {

}

class ClassA extends ClassB {

}

class ClassC {

}


public class Main extends SuperClass<ClassC>{
    @Override
    public ClassA someMethod(ClassC c) { //type safety warning in ClassA
        return null;
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the return type of `someMethod()` can be any class that extends `ClassB` or `ClassB` itself. Clearly `ClassA` is `ClassB`. What seems to be the problem and why am I getting a type safety warning?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. That would be the meaning of `public ClassB someMethod(T t)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
public <K extends ClassB> K someMethod(T t) {
    return null;
}
```

You're making a guarantee *to the callers* here. You're telling them "no matter what subclass of `SuperClass` we're working with, this method will return a value that can safely be treated as *any* subclass of `ClassB`". Then your subclass `Main` comes along and breaks that promise, by making a version that only returns `ClassA`, which is a direct violation of the contract you've made. The generic `extends` / `super` declarations are promises *to the caller*, not to the person extending the code.

Comment: It's clearer to me now. What implementation change do you suggest to get rid of type safety warning?

Comment: Either weaken your contract (change `SuperClass.someMethod` to return `ClassB`) or strengthen you subclass guarantee (make `Main.someMethod` generic as well). Which one of these is correct depends on what sort of contract you *want* to have.